# How do I count the number of unique vectors in a list?

Tags: r

Say I have a list of vectors.  I want a list of the unique vectors in that list, and their frequencies.  I can get a list of the unique values with `unique`, but I can't figure out how to get a vector of the counts.

```
my.list <- list(c(1, 1, 0), c(1, 1, 0))
> unique(my.list)  # gives correct answer
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 1 0
```

Now I want something that gives me a vector of the number of times each element of `unique(my.list)` was repeated.  In this case, that should be a vector with the element `2`.

Using `table` doesn't work, because it takes each of the elements of the vector (the 0 and 1 values) separately:

```
> table(my.list)
#          my.list.2
# my.list.1 0 1
#         0 1 0
#         1 0 2
```

Any ideas?  I would rather not `paste` these into a string and then re-separate them into vectors if I can help it.

Comment: Small question: are the vectors always the same length?

Comment: @joran Yes, they are.

Comment: In that case I might opt for keeping them in a data.frame/data.table instead. Then you can create a "key" column by paste()-ing them together and keep that info separate.

Comment: how about `table(sapply( my.list,paste,collapse = ','))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `match` on the entire list vs. the unique list:

```
my.list <- list(c(1, 1, 0), c(1, 1, 0), c(2, 1, 0))
table(match(my.list,unique(my.list)))

#1 2 
#2 1

cbind(
  data.frame(id=I(unique(my.list))),  
  count=as.vector(table(match(my.list,unique(my.list)))) 
)
#       id count
#1 1, 1, 0     2
#2 2, 1, 0     1
```

Answer (score 4):

One approach, maybe more complicated than it needs to be:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- do.call(rbind, my.list) %>% as.data.frame()
df %>% group_by_(.dots = names(df)) %>% summarise(count = n())

# Source: local data frame [1 x 4]
# Groups: V1, V2 [?]
# 
#      V1    V2    V3 count
#   (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (int)
# 1     1     1     0     2
```

---

#### Edit:

Per the comment below by @docendodiscimus, `group_by` and `summarise(n())` is equivalent to `count_`:

```
df %>% count_(names(df))    # or just count_(df, names(df))

# Source: local data frame [1 x 4]
# Groups: V1, V2 [?]
# 
#      V1    V2    V3     n
#   (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (int)
# 1     1     1     0     2
```

Comment: If you're using dplyr may as well use `bind_rows()` instead of `do.call(rbind)`. It will be faster and will fill in holes if the list elements have different numbers of elements.

Comment: @Gregor Only if the vectors are converted to data frames first, I think. Try `bind_rows(1:3,4:6)`.

Comment: `bind_rows` and  `as_data_frame` seem to be having issues, maybe because columns are not named? Not sure; it seems like even just replacing `rbind` with `bind_rows` should work, but it errors out.

Comment: You can also use `count` instead of group_by + summarise

Comment: @docendodiscimus Oh that's cool! I've found some of the `dplyr` helper functions to be a pain to integrate into chains, but the SE version of `count_` is actually great!