# Any way to remove duplicated index from list?

Tags: r, list, duplicates

I have vector list where some duplicated index exist. I intend to remove this duplication by using duplicated method, but it is not effective for get rid of this duplication. Does anyone knows any trick of doing this easily? How can I remove duplication from idxList? Any idea ?

example:

```
idxList <- list(f1=c(1,2,2,3,4,1,1,2,4,3,7),
               f2=c(1,5,5,2,3,4,4,6,1,5),
               f3=c(1,1,4,6,7,7,2,3,3,5,8))
```

I intend to use duplicated method to get rid of duplicated index, it won't effective.

my expected output would be:

```
desiredOUT <- list(
  f1=c(1,2,3,4,7),
  f2=c(1,5,2,3,4,6),
  f3=c(1,4,6,7,2,3,5)
)
```

How can I get my expected output ? Can anyone point me out how to do? Thanks in advance

Comment: lapply(idxList,function(x) x[!duplicated(x)]) maybe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I count the number of unique vectors in a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36047743/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-unique-vectors-in-a-list)

Answer (score 5):

We can apply `unique` on each of the `list` elements

```
lapply(idxList, unique)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another vision is to take `union` of each list element with itself:

```
lapply(idxList, function(x) union(x,x))
```